# How does one evaluate the derivative of a matrix with a tensor $\frac{\partial \operatorname{Tr}[A(\mathrm{Id}\otimes w)]}{\partial w}$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

I am stuck on the following:

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{Tr}[A(\mathrm{Id}\otimes w)]}{\partial w}=\text{ ?}$$

with $A$ a $d\times d^2$ matrix, $\mathrm{Id}$ the identity matrix of $d\times d$ dimension and $w$ a $d\times 1$ vector.

THANKS!!!

Comment: You need [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274). Save it!

Comment: I learned a MathJax detail from editing this. $\operatorname{Id}\otimes w$ versus $\mathrm{Id}\otimes w$.  The former uses \operatorname and the latter uses \mathrm.  I wondered why the spacing in the former was as if $\otimes$ were a unary operator rather than equal spacing on both sides of $\otimes$ as with binary operators like $+$ and $\times$.  Conclusion: Although we all know that \operatorname{} has its own spacing conventions, this corollary hadn't occurred to me.  Now I know. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and now I find that {\operatorname{Id}}\otimes w does provide proper binary-operator spacing to the left and right of $\otimes$, although \operatorname{Id}\otimes w does not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hi Micheal!

thanks for the suggestion, I know the book.
I tried to use the identities in it but still I am not able to see a simple expression for the derivative! Do you have any suggestion how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!!!

Fabio

Comment: @ Fabio , your function is linear  !!

Comment: Indeed, so that means the derivative is constant; but the issue is *what* constant :-)

Comment: Sorry if this is a simple question, but could you clarify what $A(Id \otimes w)$ means? I thought that the trace operator required a square matrix as input but $Id \otimes w$ seems to be a $(d \times d \times d)$ tensor. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Using the technique from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909404/derivative-of-a-trace-with-kronecker-product), first calculate the Kronecker factorization $$A^T=Y\otimes z$$where $(Y,z)$ are shaped like $(I,w)$ respectively.

Using this factorization and the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) you can rewrite the function, then find its differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
  f &= A^T:(I\otimes w) \cr\cr
 df &= (Y\otimes z):(I\otimes dw) \cr
    &= (I:Y)\,(z:dw) \cr
    &= {\rm tr}(Y)\,z:dw \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= z\,{\rm tr}(Y) \cr\cr
}$$
In most cases, you'll need a sum of Kronecker factors
$$A^T = \sum_{k=1}^r Y_k\otimes z_k$$
which changes the result slightly
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= \sum_{k=1}^r z_k\,{\rm tr}(Y_k) \cr\cr
}$$

Answer (score 2):

The Singular Value Decomposition 
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{k=1}^{r} \sigma_k u_k v_k^T \cr
\sigma_k&\in{\mathbb R},\,\,\,u_k\in{\mathbb R}^{d\times 1},\,\,\,v_k^T\in{\mathbb R}^{1\times d^2}
}$$
can be used to find the gradient of this function.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= I:(I\otimes w)\,A \cr
d\phi &= I:(I\otimes dw)\,A \cr
 &= \sum_kI:(I\otimes dw)\, \sigma_k u_k v_k^T \cr
 &= \sum_k\sigma_k v_k:(I\otimes dw)\,u_k \cr
 &= \sum_k\sigma_k v_k:{\rm vec}(dw\,u_k^T) \cr
 &= \sum_kM_k:dw\,u_k^T \cr
 &= \sum_kM_ku_k:dw \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} &= \sum_kM_ku_k \cr
}$$
**NB:**  The $\{M_k\}$ are $(d\times d)$ matrices such that 
$\,{\rm vec}(M_k) = \sigma_k v_k$